# Get namespace of WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf

Let's say I have a WCF service that uses the namespace "http://mynamespace.com/myservice" for all the messages (in the SOAP XML).

I add a service reference to this service in Visual Studio and start using it.

Now I want to get that namespace (the string) with code on the client side somehow, but I don't know how. Is it possible?

*(Hope you understand what I mean, I'm new to WCF and don't really know the correct terminology)*

Comment: Where do you want to get that namespace? On the client, on the server or from the outside?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: On the client side (I've edited the question to clarify that now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply find the namespace of any SOAP service you can just inspect the WSDL and look at the wsdl:definitions element. The namespace of the service will be found in the targetNamespace attribute.  You can always get to the WSDL by browsing to http://server/service.svc?wsdl

Also note that your service contracts and your data contracts have namespaces too.  The service operation namespace becomes your Soap Action and the data contract namespaces discern your types.

From a client perspective you could always look at the binding information that was generated. The endpoint configuration element should automatically expose a bindingNamespace attribute which is the namespace of the service.

If you use the WCF Test Client tool you can look at the Config File that is generated to get a better understanding of your services.

Comment: Sorry syneptody, I was unclear in my question. I want to get the namespace using code. I have edited my question to clarify that now.

Comment: Oh, in that case I think you can just interrogate the proxy class that has been generated for you. Let's say that you named your service reference MyService and you had a MyServiceClient object created for you. You could do something like MyServiceClient.Endpoint and look at all the properties that are associated with your service endpoint. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.aspx

Comment: The answer to my question is in the comment by syneptody above. The namespace was found using this code:"string ns = new MyServiceClient().Endpoint.Contract.Namespace;"